# Plupload and error generation

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, plupload

I am working on an application that uses the [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) library for file uploading. I can't seem to get the file uploading working because there is some kind of error but I can't get this error to alert or log.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Here is my current code:

```
uploader.bind('Error', function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How far do you get?  Does the file get to your server?

Comment: No the file doesn't go anywhere. But I know that an error occurs because the notification icon in the plupload dialogue is the exclamation point.

Answer (score 2):

So I know this is probably way too late, but I just started with plupload and was in a helpful mood...

The reason the console never logs anything is because the binding that you are doing only occurs when all uploads have been completed.

You need to put this code before the `$('form').submit()` line:

```
uploader = $('#plupload').pluploadQueue();
uploader.bind('Error', function(error){
   console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Binding to the error event requires two params:

```
  var uploader = $("#uploader").pluploadQueue();
  uploader.bind('Error', function(uploader, e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

Comment: For me, the `pluploadQueue()` returned a jQuery object not a `plupload.Uploader` and there was no way of accessing the latter because it was an unexposed internal variable in the widget. Maybe I missed something, but it seemed like shitty design to me.

Answer (score 1):

Another late answer. If I were you i would start with changins stuff like:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
```

into something like:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function(e) {
```

and stuff like that:

```
$('form').submit();
```

into:

```
$('form').trigger('submit');
```

Also I would move all these binds out of $(form).submit.

```
uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function() {
    if (uploader.total.uploaded == uploader.files.length)
       $('form').submit();
});
```

Just for sake of simiplicity and debugability.

Unfortunately still have no idea what's wrong with your script. Maybe you are missing:

```
uploader.init();
```

Maybe:

```
if (uploader.total.uploaded == 0) {
```

is not triggering.

Nevertheless some console.log after each line should help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my entire code base for trying to get this to work

```
$('#plupload').pluploadQueue({
        runtimes : 'flash, html5',
        url : '/admin/upload/do_upload/',
        filters : [
            {title : "Image Files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
        ],
        flash_swf_url : "/js/admin/plupload/plupload.flash.swf"
    });

    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        alert('EHY');
        var uploader = $('#plupload').pluploadQueue();

        // Validate number of uploaded files
        if (uploader.total.uploaded == 0) {
            // Files in queue upload them first
            if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
                // When all files are uploaded submit form
                uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function() {
                    if (uploader.total.uploaded == uploader.files.length)
                        $('form').submit();
                });

                uploader.start();

                uploader.bind('Error', function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            } else
                alert('You must at least upload one file.');

            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for error handling mechanism provided by Plupload widget, none of the answers were working. So here is the working one (per version 2.1.2):

```
$(FileUpload.container).pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        url: "saveFiles",
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        rename: true,
        dragdrop: true,
        multipart : true,
        unique_names : true,
        filters: {
            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size: '16mb',
            // Specify what files to browse for
            mime_types: [
                {title: "XML files", extensions: "xml"}
            ]
        },
        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',
        init : {
            Error: function(up, args) {
                // Called when error occurs
                Daedalus.localMessage("XML file is not valid!");
            }
        }
    });
```

The "init" object has more supported events, refer to http://www.plupload.com/examples/events